# How can i remove the posts category class names from body_class

Tags: categories, post-class

I have 2 categories, just to make an easy example, Cars and Bikes.
I have a post that fits both of the category.
If i visit the Cars category, the body_class looks like this:

"archive category category-cars category-1 category-cars category-bikes"

The problem is that somehow the post category is visible in the body_class after the category-1 classname. How can i avoid this? I need to use different colors for different categories, but right now the category-bikes class overwrites the category-cars class.

Answer (score 2):

This could be solved via CSS as well.  Just set up declarations for the special cases where there is overlap between categories:

```
.category-cars { background-color: #f00; }
.category-bikes,
.category-cars.category-bikes { background-color: #0f0; }
```

This will give any posts that are in both bikes and cars the same background color as those used in the bikes category.

Comment: Yes, but i have 9 categories, so this solution is not exactly what i am looking for. But thanks:) Maybe i just remove the body_class function and add the category slug to the body...

Comment: I just duplicated the get_body_class function to my functions.php, and if i change return apply_filters( 'body_class', $classes, $class ); to return $classes, it works fine. I guess something is using a filter to hook up those extra category classes, but i can't find it anywhere...